# Why there is no strnchr function?

Tags: c

As the other C library function, like `strcpy`, `strcat`, there is a version which limits the size of string (`strncpy`, etc.), I am wondering why there is no such variant for `strchr`?

Comment: Why would you need it?  What does `memchr()` not do that `strnchr()` would do?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Presumably `strnchr()` would stop once either the terminator were hit *or* the maximum length was hit. `strchr_s` might be a better name. But of course if you've got an overflowed string in your dataset, you've already lost.

Comment: @Sneftel: Hmmm…interesting…If you don't know how long the null terminated string is but know that it is not longer than N bytes, and you are only interested in searching the first M bytes at most, and M < N, but the actual length of the null-terminated string, L, could be less than M, then `memchr()` is not quite identical to the hypothetical `strnchr()`.  Legitimate, even if not very likely.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeh, I'd definitely put it in the "write your own" category of general utility functions.

Comment: @Sneftel: I agree. It could make sense to have such a function.

Comment: Not all the other C string library functions have such a variant. strnstr() only exists as a non-standard extension in some compilers, maybe only the FreeBSD version of gcc. It isn't in POSIX or any C/C++ standard version.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It does exist -- it is called `memchr`:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling

Comment: Note that `memchr` is not *exacly* what one might expect `strnchr` might do, since `memchr` does not stop at the end of the string if it is shorter than the `n` argument (i.e. it can read bytes beyond the `\0`, unlike `strchr`). The "n-less" equivalent of `memchr` is not `strchr`, but `rawmemchr`, a GNU extension that is not POSIX nor C99.

Comment: So `#define strnchr(haystack, needle, length) memchr(haystack, needle, strnlen(haystack, length))` should do it, right?

Answer (score 8):

In C, the term "string" usually means "null terminated array of characters", and the `str*` functions operate on those kinds of strings. The `n` in the functions you mention is mostly for the sake of controlling the *output*.

If you want to operate on an arbitary *byte* sequence without any implied termination semantics, use the `mem*` family of functions; in your case `memchr` should serve your needs.

Comment: Good insight, but examples of existing functionality where a bound is provided for an input string are `strncmp()` and `printf("%.*s", n, s);`. Note that a proper manpage for `strncmp` would avoid saying that it takes strings as argument, but the BSD and GNU manpages are a bit sloppy in this regard. The C standard on the other hand is perfectly worded.

Comment: Also POSIX's `strnlen()`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Interesting. I would probably look twice at any algorithm that alleges to be a good use case for `strnlen`.

Comment: A use case for `strnlen` is, when implementing `printf`, if both a width and a precision have been provided for a string format, in order to compute the number of leading spaces that should be printed.

Answer (score 0):

strnchr and also strnlen are defined in some linux environments, for example https://manpages.debian.org/experimental/linux-manual-4.11/strnchr.9.en.html. It is really necessary. A program may crash on end of memory area if strlen or strcmp do not found any \0-termination. Unfortunately such things often are not standardized or too late and too sophisticated standardized. strnlen_s is existing in C11, but strnchr_s is not available.

You may found some more information about such problems in my internet page: https://www.vishia.org/emcdocu/html/portability_emC.html. I have defined some C-functions strnchr_emC... etc. which delivers the required functionality. To achieve compatibility you can define

```
#define strnchr strnchr_emC
```

In a common header but platform-specific. Refer the further content on https://www.vishia.org/emc/. You find the sources in https://github.com/JzHartmut